# Getting Artifactory Plugin to work with Jenkins and Maven

Tags: maven, jenkins, artifactory

I have a large Maven project in Jenkins. It consists of a parent project, and about a dozen local projects. Using Jenkins, I am able to do `mvn`deploy` and for the build to successfully deploy to my Artifactory repository.

However, I can't seem to get the Jenkin's Artifactory plugin to work itself to work.

My Artifactory setting in Jenkins:

[image: Jenkins Artifactory Master Setting]

And here's the setting for our job:

[image: Job Artifactory Setting]

Comment: Did you solved this problem. I have same problem here. Simply mvn clean install doesn't trigger artifactory deployer as expected. My configuration seems very likely to yours. Thanks.

Comment: No. I simply just used `mvn deploy`. Works.

Answer (score 3):

When using the Jenkins Artifactory Plugin you should execute `mvn install` instead of `mvn deploy`.
This is because the plugin collects the published artifacts from Maven and when executing `mvn deploy` directly you are kind of by-passing it's behavior.

Comment: We were executing the _install_ target because I wanted the plugin to do the job. However, I changed this to _deploy_ when I realized that the plugin wasn't working because I wanted the artifacts to be deployed anyway. As soon as I can figure out what the error is, I'll switch this back to _install_. I'm going to add the console output to my question. That might help.

Comment: target _package_ is not enough ?

Answer (score 0):

Use Build Step "Invoke Artifactory Maven 3" when working with Artifactory plugin. And most preferably use goals "clean install"

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and resolved by adding details under `Build Environment -> Generic-Artifactory Integration` as shown in below image

[image: Blockquote]

Published Artifacts now started uploading into desired location in artifactory.